# PS4 remote won't connect to PS4 after being connected to iPad while PS4 has error message

Tags: controllers

I have been playing PS4 through my iPad, with the remote connected via Bluetooth to the iPad. Just recently the PS4 crashed and when it restarted, there is an error message which gives you an option to report to Sony. I cannot press this with the remote since the remote connects through my iPad app and the iPad app needs the PS4 to be on and connected (not in the error message mode it turns to).

I tried to connect the controller via the options and PS button, I tried with the wire, I tried disconnecting from iPad and forgetting device from it as well, nothing is working. I can't even go to safe mode since I can't use the controller. I have a second controller and that one doesn’t connect through wire either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You need to plug the controller back into the PS4 and hit the PS button. This will re pair it with the ps4.